# complex looping using Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment

Let there be five matrices given as:

```
 A=  [A1 A1 A1 A1 A1; A2 A2 A2 A2 A2; A3 A3 A3 A3 A3]

 B= [B1 B1 B1  B1  B1; B2 B2  B2 B2 B2;B3 B3 B3 B3 B3]

 C=[ C1 C1 C1 C1 C1; C2 C2 C2 C2 C2; C3 C3 C3 C3 C3]

 D= [D1 D1 D1 D1 D1 ; D2 D2 D2 D2 D2; D3 D3 D3 D3 D3]

 E=[ E1 E1 E1 E1 E1; E2 E2 E2 E2 E2; E3 E3 E3 E3 E3]
```

I want to make a program such that ouput consists of taking each row of each given matrix and forming a new matrix. how to use looping in such cases when length of matrices increases and number of given matrices also increases. This problem seemed to me a complex one. Because I want to generalize by using loop and output for any number of matrices say 20 and having number of columns also increased to say 25, then how to get these P1 to P20 outputs. Can anyone help me regarding this complex trouble using Matlab

```
P1=[ A1 A1  A1 A1 A1; B1 B1 B1 B1 B1; C1 C1 C1 C1 C1 C1; D1 D1 D1 D1 D1; E1 E1 E1 E1 E1]
P2=[ A2 A2  A2 A2 A2; B2 B2 B2 B2 B2; C2 C2 C2 C2 C2 C2; D2 D2 D2 D2 D2; E2 E2 E2 E2 E2]
```

and similarly other matrices is obtained .

Note: That the given 5 matrices are generated with help of loop. So first I would be getting values as :

```
  A= A1
  B= B1
  C=C1
  D=D1
  E=E1

  A= A1 A1 
  B= B1 B1
  C=C1  C1
  D=D1  D1
  E=E1  E1 .... AND SO ON
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a loop and put all the matrix together to form a 3D tensor. Or just put the matrices in the 3D tensor when they are created.

```
M(:,:,1) = A; M(:,:,2) = B; etc
```

then

```
squeeze(M(1,:,:))' is the P1, squeeze(M(2,:,:))' is the P2
```

Example:

```
M(:,:,1) =

     1     2
     3     4


M(:,:,2) =

     5     6
     7     8

>> squeeze(M(1,:,:))'

ans =

     1     2
     5     6
```

Comment: Thanks but how to generalize it when number of given matrices is large and also columns also being large. Then I want to use some sort of method by which I simultaneously generated outputs say P1,..... P100

Comment: I think it can already generalize, just put your bigger matrices in M and loop through the rows

Comment: For the edited post which I have done just now, s still your technique will work. I mean to say that each value is generated one-by one in a loop but I think your method requires that all the values should be first generated and after that squeeze method could be applied. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: This only requires that the size is known before starting.  The values can be assigned individually.

Comment: while using your method the following error is what is diplayed Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton
subscripts. Where might be the problem while using this method.